# Problems with instaling SFML

Tags: software-engineering, sfml, mingw

I've followed the instructions on [installing SFML](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/start-cb.php) on the website to the letter. But, I get this when I try to build the sample program on the same page using Code::Blocks.

```
C:\Users\nic\Desktop\sfmltest.o:sfmltest.cxx|| undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6StringC1EPKcRKSt6locale'|

...

||=== Build failed: 20 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I get 20 error messages, which are all similar to the one given above. SFML worked like a charm on my ubuntu 14.04 amd64 install, but it simply does not work on Windows. I am using SFML 2.1 (the GCC 4.7 TDM (SJLJ) - 64 bits package as the other ones did not work) on a Windows 7 x64 installation with MinGW (gcc 4.8.1). How can I make SFML work on Windows?

edit: I'm not sure if I have to copy-paste all the SFML dlls to the working directory. Should I do this?

edit2: c/ping the dlls does not help.

Comment: Did you try building from source with CMake?

Comment: DLLs are only important at runtime, you have a compile-time error. Judging by the error message I would guess that your compiler fails to find the .lib files, are you sure you have the correct path in the linker settings?

Comment: @UnholySheep Unfortunately, everything was correctly configured the second time I checked, yet I get the same errors :(

Comment: In your question you state that you are using GCC 4.6.2 with libraries that have been compiled with GCC 4.7 - My best guess is that this is causing problems (you should always try to match the compiler version the library used). You should try either upgrading your own compiler or recompiling the library from source, as fastinvsqrt suggested

Comment: @UnholySheep, sadly, even after updating MinGW to gcc 4.8.1 I still get the same problem.

Comment: And recompiling the library didn't help either?

Comment: @UnholySheep I haven't tried that. Which library do I need to recompile and how?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about setting up a development environment. You may want to ask about this in the [chat], but it is not an appropriate question for the main site.

Comment: @JoshPetrie I understand, but I feel my problem is more complicated and needs a more complete answer. Is putting this out on SO okay?